# Reveiving a HTTP POST request, how can I get the line after the blank line in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, webserver, httprequest

My program seems stopped after the blank line detected until I press the stop button in broswer.

Before the stop button is pressed:

[image]

After the stop button is pressed:

[image]

Here is part of the code:

```
while (accept CONNECTION, SERVER ) {
  select CONNECTION; $| = 1; select STDOUT;
  print "\n>> Client connected at ", scalar(localtime), "\n";

  my $isGet = 1;
  my $isPostAndBlankLineDetected = 0;
  while (<CONNECTION>) {
    s/\r?\n//;
    my $msg = $_;
    rubyP "$msg";

    if ($msg  =~ /GET/) {
      processGet($msg);
      last;
    }

    if ($msg  =~ /POST/) {
      setReqMethodAndReturnUri($msg);
      $isGet = 0;
    }

    if ($isPostAndBlankLineDetected) {
      pp "isPostAndBlankLineDetected is true";
      last;
    }

    if( ! $isGet) { #isPost
      if ($msg  =~ /Content-Length/) {
        setContentLength($msg);
      }

      if ($msg eq "") {
        $isPostAndBlankLineDetected = 1;
        pp "done setting isPostAndBlankLineDetected";
      }
    }
  }

  close CONNECTION;
  print ">> Client disconnected\n";
}
```

I have a `last` statement in `if ($isPostAndBlankLineDetected)`.

Here is the socket part:

```
use Socket;

require "helper.pl";

sub rubyP { #print raw string
  my $arg = $_;

  use Data::Dumper;
  $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
  print Dumper $arg;

}


sub pp {
  print "DEBUG: '$_[0]'\n";
}



my $protocol = getprotobyname 'tcp';

my $port = 15032;
my $server_addr = sockaddr_in($port, INADDR_ANY);

socket SERVER, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $protocol
  or die "Unable to create socket: $!";

bind SERVER, $server_addr
  or die "Unable to bind: $!";

listen SERVER, SOMAXCONN;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to implement your own HTTP server rather than using one off CPAN? There's a ton of really good implementations already out there -- `HTTP::Server::Simple` and `Starlet` are two good ones to take a look at using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You falsely assume there is a "line" that follows. Even if something follows, it might not be ended by have a newline.

[`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) `Content-Length` bytes.

Comment: there is no such line? but `$VAR1 = "";
DEBUG: 'done setting isPostAndBlankLineDetected'
$VAR1 = "id=1&passwd=1";` syas there is one.